# why pointer type can access all methods of embed type

Tags: go

The following is the source code to try the embed type.

**Modify** function is defined  as **func (f *F) Modify(f2 F)**. Could anyone explain why the **Modify** function is not shown in the first reflection loop? But in the second reflection loop, both **Modify** and **Validate** can be got from *s.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type F func(int) bool
func (f F) Validate(n int) bool {
    return f(n)
}
func (f *F) Modify(f2 F) {
    *f = f2
}

type B bool
func (b B) IsTrue() bool {
    return bool(b)
}
func (pb *B) Invert() {
    *pb = !*pb
}

type I interface {
    Load()
    Save()
}

func PrintTypeMethods(t reflect.Type) {
    fmt.Println(t, "has", t.NumMethod(), "methods:")
    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Print(" method#", i, ": ",
                t.Method(i).Name, "\n")
    }
}

func main() {
    var s struct {
        F
        *B
        I
    }

    PrintTypeMethods(reflect.TypeOf(s))
    fmt.Println()
    PrintTypeMethods(reflect.TypeOf(&s))
}
```

output:

```
struct { main.F; *main.B; main.I } has 5 methods:
 method#0: Invert
 method#1: IsTrue
 method#2: Load
 method#3: Save
 method#4: Validate

*struct { main.F; *main.B; main.I } has 6 methods:
 method#0: Invert
 method#1: IsTrue
 method#2: Load
 method#3: Modify
 method#4: Save
 method#5: Validate
```

Comment: Because the language spec says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Method sets`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
> interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T
> consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set
> of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods
> declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
> set of T). **Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields,
> as described in the section on struct types.** Any other type has an
> empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
> non-blank method name.

[`Struct types`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field or method f of an embedded field in a struct x is called
> **promoted** if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method
> f.

...

> Given a struct type S and a defined type T, **promoted methods** are
> included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - `If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.`
> - If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

Comment: Is the last part also from language spec?

Comment: @shuming yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

If a method `m` is defined for a type `T`, that method is available for both `T` and `*T`:

```
type T struct {}

func (t T) m() {}

func main() {
   t:=T{}
   tp:=&T{}
   t.m()   // valid: m defined for T
   tp.m()  // valid: m defined for *T
}
```

If a method is defined with a pointer receiver, it is only defined for `*T` and not for `T'`:

```
func (t *T) n() {}

func main() {
   t:=T{}
   tp:=&TP{
   t.n() // Valid: &t is passed to n
   tp.b  // valid

   mp:=map[int]T{1:t}
   mp[1].n() // not valid. mp[1] is not addressable
   pp:=map[int]*T{1:&t}
   pp[1].n() // valid: pp[1] is *T
}
```

The reason for this is simple: it prevents unintentionally modifying the copy instead of the indented object. If a method with pointer receiver was available for the value type as well, with the following code:

```
mp[1].n()
```

`n`, taking a pointer receiver, would have modified a copy of the value of `mp[1]`, and not the value stored at `mp[1]`. The fact that methods with pointer receivers are not available for value types prevents that, and this becomes a compile error, because `n` is not defined for `T`, and `mp[1]` is not addressable, preventing the value to be converted to a pointer by the compiler.